# unknown reason struts project is not working correctly?

Tags: java, xml, struts2

i have done everything correctly but its not working

[image]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>m2r</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>weldcome.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**strut2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>

   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.tut.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

**HelloWorldAction**

```
package com.tut.struts2;

public class HelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport {
     private String name;

       public String execute() throws Exception {
          return "success";
       }

       public String getName() {
          return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
       }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
   <form action="hello">
      <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not working correctly - elaborate

Comment: index page is working but HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name hello.

Comment: Could not find action or result
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name hello. - [unknown location]

Comment: helloworld jsp in webcontent folder is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your mapping in `struts.xml` is wrong. In `struts.xml`, you have `<result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>`, the framework will just append the `context path` to `/HelloWorld.jsp` and use it to locate your `HellowWorld.jsp`. But from the image that you posted, `HelloWorld.jsp` is located in the `WEB-INF` directory. This is why struts cannot locate your jsp. Remap the jsp in `struts.xml` or change the location of `HelloWorld.jsp` to reflect the current mapping. I think this will solve your issues.

**Edit**
Change `struts2.xml` to `struts.xml`

Comment: still its not working,its not entering the action class..before that program terminates..

Comment: @404 What url are you using to access the application. Can you post it?

Comment: @404 Try localhost:8080/m2r/hello. I am assuming that `m2r` is your context path. Please post your complete `web.xml` so that i can check if it has issues.

Comment: @404 Though this is not the cause of your issue, can you change the url mapping `<url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>` of the filter to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`. Test the url that i posted and see if it works. Please also change `struts2.xml` to `struts.xml`.

Comment: tried but no way..i am doing this yesterday onwards but still dont know what the the problem...I have tried every things i know

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45861/discussion-between-uchenna-nwanyanwu-and-404)